# Ignoring values when using apply with mean

Tags: r, apply, mean

I want to exclude values when calculating the mean with apply(x,1,mean):

```
#Example data:
df <- data.frame(A1 = c(0,1,2,3,4,2,NA,5,6), 
                 A2 = c(5,0,0,4,NA,5,3,2,1), 
                 A3 = c(0,0,1,2,4,5,3,4,3), 
                 B1 = c(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9))

#I am using grep, because I need to use specific parts of the column names and I can not use the index
df$MEANA <- apply(df[,grep("A", colnames(df))],1,mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This gives me the mean values, ignoring the NA values

```
df$MEANA
[1] 1.6666667 0.3333333 1.0000000 3.0000000 4.0000000 4.0000000 3.0000000 3.6666667 3.3333333
```

I want to also ignore the 0s. I can do this by changing the 0s to NAs. Or by setting 0s as NA when reading in the data.

My question: can I ignore the 0s in the apply command, like I can do with na.rm = TRUE? (for example ignore.value = 0) I am new to the apply concept and don't know if it is possible.

UPDATE:

```
aind <- grep("A", names(df))
#ignore NAs
df$M1 <- apply(df[,grep("A", colnames(df))],1,mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#Ignore 0 and 6 and NA
df$M2 <-rowMeans(sapply(df[aind], function(x) replace(x, x %in% c(0, 6), NA)), na.rm = TRUE)
#ignore 0 and NA
df$M3 <- rowMeans(replace(df[aind], df[aind] == 0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)

df

    > A1 A2 A3 B1        M1       M2       M3
1  0  5  0  9 1.6666667 5.000000 5.000000
2  1  0  0  9 0.3333333 1.000000 1.000000
3  2  0  1  9 1.0000000 1.500000 1.500000
4  3  4  2  9 3.0000000 3.000000 3.000000
5  4 NA  4  9 4.0000000 4.000000 4.000000
6  2  5  5  9 4.0000000 4.000000 4.000000
7 NA  3  5  9 4.0000000 4.000000 4.000000
8  5  2  4  9 3.6666667 3.666667 3.666667
9  6  0  4  9 3.3333333 4.000000 5.000000
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lamdba function and then it would be easier

```
aind <- grep("A", names(df))
apply(df[aind], 1, function(x) mean(x[x !=0], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or use the vectorized `rowMeans` after `replace`ing the 0 to `NA` which would be faster

```
rowMeans(replace(df[aind], df[aind] == 0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

If we need to set multiple values, use `%in%` on a `vector` instead of `==` as `==` is elementwise comparison and this can recycle values creating incorrect results

```
rowMeans(sapply(df[aind], function(x) 
       replace(x, x %in% c(0, 6), NA)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go with the rowMeans solution, because it doesnt change the original dataframe and it looks much nicer and understandable than the apply command.

Comment: @BanffBoss122 the `replace` doesn't change the original object

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant! Is there a way to set multiple values to NA? e.g. 0 and 6?

Comment: I think the 0,6 line ist working, see my updated post.

Comment: @BanffBoss122 sorry, that was a mistake.  I will correct it

Comment: @BanffBoss122 Can you try now

Comment: perfect! Thank you, I will look into the difference to figure out how it is working in detail!

Comment: @BanffBoss122 The issue is that `%in%` requires vector, but we provided a data.frame whereas `==` can work on data.frame as it is elementwise

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
df[df == 0] <- NA
```

and then your code:

```r
df$MEANA <- apply(df[,grep("A", colnames(df))],1,mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I especially want to avoid changing the values, so I will go with the solution akrun posted ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(MeanA = c_across(starts_with('A')) %>% na_if(0) %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE))

# # A tibble: 9 x 5
# # Rowwise: 
#      A1    A2    A3    B1 MeanA
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0     5     0     9  5   
# 2     1     0     0     9  1   
# 3     2     0     1     9  1.5 
# 4     3     4     2     9  3   
# 5     4    NA     4     9  4   
# 6     2     5     5     9  4   
# 7    NA     3     3     9  3   
# 8     5     2     4     9  3.67
# 9     6     1     3     9  3.33
```